# Sending big files into a telegram chat using bot api and requests library (python 3.6)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-api

I'm trying to send a long video to a telegram chat using python 3.6 with the following code:

```
import requests
files = {'document':open('video.avi', 'rb') }
resp = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument?chat_id=<chatid>', files = files, timeout = None )
```

My problem is that even after I set the timeout as 'none', I keep getting an exception after about 30 seconds.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening and allow me to get a timeout as long as I need to upload any file of any dimension?

Comment: Does the file size exceeds Telegram's max size limit?

Comment: No, I am able to send that same file manually